# How to draw linked-list in graphviz without cross the node?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, graphviz

I've defined a `list_t` structure and a `list_node_t` structure as follows:

```
typedef struct taglist_node_t {
    struct taglist_node_t  *pstNext;
    void                   *pData;
} list_node_t;

typedef struct taglist_t {
    list_node_t     stHead;
    list_node_t    *pstTail;
    unsigned int    uiCount;
} list_t;
```

And I decide to draw the above linked-list using graphviz, and the code as here:

```
digraph g {
    bgcolor="#BBCAF2";
    label="\nSingle Linked List\n";

    graph[rankdir=LR, center=true, margin=0.2, nodesep=1, ranksep=1]
    edge[arrowsize=1.0, arrowhead=vee]
    node[shape = Mrecord, fontname="Consolas", fontsize=20, width=1, height=1, fixedsize=false];

    list[label = "<name> slist_t | <head> stHead | <tail> *pstTail | uiCount"];
    node0[label = "<name> list_node_t | <next> *pstNext | *pData"];
    node1[label = "<name> list_node_t | <next> *pstNext | *pData"];
    head[label = "pstList"];

    head -> list:name[style=bold, color=red, dir=both, arrowtail=dot];
    list:head:e -> node0:name[dir=forward, arrowtail=normal];
    list:tail:e -> node1:name[dir=both, arrowtail=dot];
    node0:next:e -> list:head:w[dir=both, arrowtail=dot];
    node1:next:e -> list:head:w[dir=both, arrowtail=dot, color=blue];
}
```

But as you can see from the following result, the **blue** line cross the other nodes. And my question is how to avoid this or move the blue line below the node1 in order to avoid edge crossing?

The GraphViz result:

[image: GraphViz .dot output]

Comment: This isn't about the graphviz part, but you have *two* elements in your single linked list (of type list_node_t), yet there is no link in between them. No matter how I look at it, this looks like a branching structure. Or have I completely missed something???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically there is no solution for this problem. you can play with the parameters to optimize a concrete layout but not in general.

increasing weight for the blue edge gives the most acceptable layout.

```
digraph g {
    bgcolor="#BBCAF2";
    label="\nSingle Linked List\n";

    graph[rankdir=LR, center=true, margin=0.2, nodesep=1, ranksep=1]
    edge[arrowsize=1.0, arrowhead=vee]
    node[shape = Mrecord, fontname="Consolas", fontsize=20, width=1, height=1, fixedsize=false];

    list[label = "<name> slist_t | <head> stHead | <tail> *pstTail | uiCount"];
    node0[label = "<name> list_node_t | <next> *pstNext | *pData"];
    node1[label = "<name> list_node_t | <next> *pstNext | *pData"];
    head[label = "pstList"];

    head -> list:name[style=bold, color=red, dir=both, arrowtail=dot];
    list:head:e -> node0:name[dir=forward, arrowtail=normal];
    list:tail:e -> node1:name[dir=both, arrowtail=dot];
    node0:next:e -> list:head:w[dir=both, arrowtail=dot];
    node1:next:e -> list:head:w[dir=both, arrowtail=dot, color=blue, weight=10];
}
```

But `node0` should not have an edge to `list` anyway, most probable it should point to `node1`. And `node1` should not point anywhere.

Finally to your C implementation - `stHead` shall be a pointer as well.